How to control the filename of a PDF opened in a new browser tab?
I'm working on a web application where we generate PDF reports on the server side and send them to the client. When the user clicks a button on the frontend, the PDF is opened in a new browser tab. However, the filename of the PDF in the new tab is a random number generated by the browser.
Here's the relevant part of my server-side code (in C#):
byte[] pdf = report.Render("PDF");
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdf);
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = $"Report_{adNo}.pdf";
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
return response;

I've set the FileName property of the Content-Disposition header to a specific filename, but this only seems to affect the filename when the PDF is downloaded, not when it's viewed in the browser.
Is there a way to control the filename of the PDF when it's opened in a new browser tab? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Have you checked whether the "random number" actually is the title in the PDF Info dictionary?

The Master control for a tab is usually the HTML carrier .
So when a PDF is downloaded in a Chromium based browser, it does not usually use the  PDF file name or its contents it uses the outer wrap. Here I have altered the Microsoft carrier and you can see the HTML Page Title is the overarching control.

The download has no inherent name it is simply application/pdf

Same browser, same PDF download, nothing changed  apart from the method of wrapping and now the Page Title is ignored and the URL used as the Tab Title. So without a HTML Page Title the URL is the fallback, and if that URL is a blob in another page it will be the Blob ID.

When a PDF is returned to a browser from the internal download (could be about:blank) It will then use the Documents internal title


Answer
So in most browsers, it is usually similar, but not guaranteed.

1=HTML Title around the iframed embeded object.
2 If open in new tab it should be the remote files document title.


The remote file may be built live online as a BLOB, check to see if the date and time are today. But not all browsers will use the document title simply the source URL. Here Using Acrobat and SumatraPDF plugins as secured readers neither expose the document title to the browser.

